# Redirect Spotify Connection

Tags: networking, redirection, spotify, arp

At my home I have two computers: At one I have a connection to a Hi-Fi system and I use Spotify in it. I usually use remote desktop from the other computer to change the songs but now I'm wondering if is posible do an ARP Poisoning in the network to hijack de Spotify Desktop Client connection and change the songs from my mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you download the app `Spotify Controller`? I can see it on Google Play Store (for Android), you can see it disucssed [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cewan.spotify&hl=en). The intro states:

> Description
>
> Spotify Controller lets you control the real Spotify UI on your computer.
>
> Supports Windows, Linux and Mac (Experimental).
>
> Spotify Controller lets you control the official Spotify program on your computer.
>
> Requirements:
>
> - The official Spotify client must be installed on your computer. Please make sure that you can start Spotify and play music with it, prior to using SpotifyController.
> - Linux or Windows. For Linux you must use the the Linux version of Spotify (not the one running under Wine). We have tested SpotifyController on Windows XP, Windows Vista, Windows 7, Ubuntu. If you get it to work on other versions/platforms please inform us so we can update this information.
> - To be able to populate app with playlists/songs you must have the official Spotify app installed on your device.
>
> Features:
>
> - Start/stop song
> - Skip to next/previous song
> - Use the official Spotify app to populate your own favorite list of playlists and songs
> - Control the volume (using the volume buttons on the device)
> - Configure multiple servers, e.g. if you want to control more than one computer
> - Shortcut in notification bar for easy access (can be disabled)
> - Change color theme
> - Show album art (can be disabled)
> - Animations (can be disabled)
> - Supports both phones (normal screen size) and tablets (large screens)

And on and on.

Answer (score 0):

[Spotify Connect](https://www.spotify.com/us/connect/) will also solve this problem for you. It's just been rolled out, but will eventually be available on all platforms which Spotify is available on.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I experience this on my Ubuntu 14.04 Computer I can't control Spotify via "Connect" on my Mobile Android Device. Only works with Windows ...

So Spotify Controller is the only working solution!